# How to implement complex filter query with join table in supabase from flutter?

Tags: flutter, supabase

I want to implement complex filter query in `supabase` with `flutter`.

**Table1**: `diaries` has below fields.

- diaryId
- userId (linked with table `users`)
- todayDiary
- createdAt

**Table2**: `users` has below fields.

- userId
- name
- age

**Table3**: `block_diaries` has below fields.

- userId (linked with table `users`)
- diaryId (linked with table 'diaries`)

**Table3**: `block_users` has below fields.

- userId (linked with table `users`)
- userId (linked with table 'users`)

---

1. When user block diary, it goes to table `block_diaries`.
2. When user block user, it goes to table `block_users`.

I want to fetch all diaries whose **diaryId** is not blocked by logged in user and whose **userId** is not blocked by logged in user.

In this case How can I filtered data from supabase in flutter?

I can't find complex filter query with join table with supabase, please help me.

Comment: If your needs is become more complex, use supabase RPC. But you must understand about PLPGSQL language.  Here the implementation in javascript, [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6nnp9AINJk&ab_channel=Supabase). Do any SQL command on supabase server function, then you just call the function name in flutter.

Comment: You could probably implement the blocking logic in RLS, which would eliminate the need to add filters when querying the data.